# Ideal in $A[x]$ generated by $a,x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

In an integral domain, it is a trivial exercise that an ideal of $A[X]$ generated by $a \in A$ and $X$ is principal if and only if $a$ is invertible or zero (All rings in this post are commutative with unit). I am wondering whether it is true for any ring $A$.

I think that the statement "If a proper principal ideal of $A[X]$ contains $X$ then it is generated by $X$" is also valid, but I haven't come up with proof yet.

Comment: The claim that "If a principal ideal of $A[x]$ contains $x$ then it is generated by $x$ is false; $x \in (1)$, but $(1) \neq (x)$.

Comment: @user1090793 yes definitely, I have added "proper".

Comment: $\langle 0, X\rangle = \langle X\rangle$ which is principal even though $0$ is not invertible. I think the exercise you refer to should be amended to say "if and only if $a$ is invertible or zero."

Comment: @shoteyes edited, many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true. Consider the ring $A=\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$. We have the principal ideal $(2x+3)$ contains $x$, as $$(2x+3)(3x+2)=x$$

But it's clear that $2x+3\not\in(x)$.

Note that $(2x+3)\not=(1)$. For one thing, the constant term of $(2x+3)p(x)$ is always divisible by $3$. And it's actually easy to check that $$(2x+3)=(x,3)=\{3a_0+\sum_{i=1}^na_ix^i | a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_n \in \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z\}$$

In retrospect, there is a more general construction (by splitting $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$ using CRT): Consider the product ring $A=A_1\times A_2$ where neither of $A_1, A_2$ is trivial. Then we have $p(x)=(1,0)x+(0,1)$ contains $x$ since $$[(1,0)x+(0,1)][(0,1)x+(1,0)]=x$$

But $p(x)\not\in(x)$.